# Why is addition without overflow set CC.CF to 1?

Tags: cuda, ptx

I have the next code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void cuda_test() {
    int result;
    asm(
    ".reg .u32 r1;\n\t"
    "add.cc.u32 r1, 0, 0;\n\t"
    "subc.u32 %0, 0, 0; \n\t"
    :"=r"(result)
    );
    printf("r= %x\n", result);
}

int main() {

    cuda_test<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

This code prints

```
r= ffffffff
```

Why? As far, as I undertand, operation `add.cc.u32 r1, 0, 0` must set carry flag to `0`. I am under the impression that the `subc.u32` operation uses the inverse of the `CC.CF`. But from the documentation it shouldn't be that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find information anywhere in the [PTX documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) on how what PTX calls the `CC.CF` flag is actually generated. Looking at the generated machine code (SASS) I see that subtraction is implemented via addition, and the use of an extend flag `CC.X`.

Based on some quick experiments, this `.X` flag always *seems* to be the normal carry-out from the adder. Since `a-b` = `a+~b+1`, on a subtraction `.X` will be set if `a >= b`. It represents the carry-out from the adder which is the one's complement of an x86-style borrow on subtracts, which is set when `a < b`.

In other words, the extended arithmetic instructions of the GPU appear to use the same convention that is used by the ARM and PowerPC architectures for their extended arithmetic instructions. The Wikipedia article on the [carry flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) covers the two design alternatives for handling of the flag during subtraction.

In the code in the question, `add.cc.u32` clears `CC.CF`, which signals to the subsequent `subc.u32` that a borrow has occured, causing it to compute `a+~b`.

You may wish to file an enhancement request with NVIDIA to clarify the PTX documentation regarding details of `CC.CF` generation and handling.